# Flaw in the Close Vote Review audit fail text

Tags: feature-request, review-audits, wording

I just failed a close vote audit. The quality of the audit is arguable, but that's not the point here.

The point is what it told me afterwards.

> ### STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. There are no major problems with this question. You should click Leave Open, or make minor corrections via Edit.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this answer appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

This time, I actually read the text (I had nothing else to do...) and noticed something in the last paragraph:

> Don't worry, we've already handled this **answer** appropriately – but please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the guidance above.

Uhh... Wait a minute. Did I just fail a CV audit for an *answer*? We can close answers?

No, it was a Gen-U-Wine Question, but the review audit failed text doesn't seem to know that.

Could we change 'answer' to 'question', to avoid confusion for those who actually read the text?